# Are all metaphysical claims flawed since they can't be proven?

Tags: metaphysics

Are all metaphysical claims flawed since they can't be proven? What's considered a flaw in a metaphysical claim if all of them can't be proven? Are there different types of flaw?

Comment: In one sense, all claims are "flawed" because none of them can be "proven" to everybody's satisfaction. In another sense, with a standard of evidence specific to a community and a subject matter, people find some of them plausible enough to endorse. The type of "flaw" depends on the standard, it is one in everyday life, another in courts of law,  another in science, yet another in metaphysics or theology, etc.

Answer (score -1):

What's a metaphysical claim? Incapability of proof would not per se make a claim flawed - few claims can be proven true, and scientific claims are not among them; the latter are trustworthy to the extent that they account for the evidence. A shorthand (!) answer, then, might be that metaphysical claims are flawed because they are indifferent towards the evidence, that is, because you can neither disprove them empirically. In other words, they teach you nothing of interest.